# Mysterious: `require "rubygems"` inside controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I working on some legacy code (written by someone else) in a Rails 4.1 app and I noticed...

`require "rubygems"`

...at the top of one of the controllers. I think I'm pretty familiar with how Rails works, but that is confusing to me. Is there a good reason why that should be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be there only if the app uses **Ruby v1.8**
If the app uses **Ruby v1.9+** then it is not necessary.

Source: http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics